# Ubuntu keeps re-enabling my primary laptop screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have a setup where a laptop is connected to a TV. The configuration I want is that the laptop display should always be disabled, and the TV output (DisplayPort) should always be the default.

This works fine for most of the time, and while it's not instantly reproducible, it does happen every time I shut off my TV for a longer time that the screen is all jumbled when I come back. Clicking a certain place on the screen does not "match reality" (the click actually happens somewhere else), and so on.

The way I'm currently fixing this issue is by doing this every time the issue happens -- I also run this on every login:

```
xrandr --auto
xrandr --output LVDS-1-1 --off
xrandr --output LVDS-0 --off
```

`--auto` basically enables all screens with default settings (as I understand it), and the two commands after shuts off the `LVDS` displays. This always fixes the issue, but the issue always returns, even when the system has just been idling.

So my question is, why is the `--off` setting not permanent, and how do I stop Ubuntu from being "smart" and turning my laptop screen back online?

This is the output from `xrandr` if it's needed: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24799565/

Comment: I could imagine that naming the graphics driver and version and / or Ubuntu version might be helpful in this case.

Comment: Sorry, it's 17.04 with nvidia 375.66 (package "nvidia-375"). I don't think it's necessarily relevant though as I have gotten the same issue without proprietary drivers and on other versions of Ubuntu, but I'm not sure.